# Should I use larger pipe to supply several water line branches?

Tags: water

I got a house with no running water in the middle of the forest up north in Sweden. They are going to drill a well soon and bring the water in the kitchen, from there I should find a way to bring the water also to the bathroom. In the bathroom are: sink, shower, washing machine and water heater.

I was thinking to use 12 mm copper pipes to supply each appliance, also because the only pipe bender I can find is for 12 mm pipes, but I have some questions:

From the kitchen to the bathroom it will be a single pipe for all the appliances. Would it be advisable to use a bigger 15 mm pipe (it's a 4 m run)? Then, once in the bathroom, I can reduce to 12 mm with a T-junction and reach every appliance. I want to avoid any possible bottleneck, but at the same time I have the sensation that a reduction in size can be a bottleneck too...

I have no experience at all, so any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What size are they bringing into the kitchen?

Comment: Get the water first. Get the water tested. Some water you do NOT want in copper pipes (if it's acid water, it will eat through them in time.) Plastic can be better, in that case - or go to stainless steel (which is commonly available in some places, and may be cheaper than copper if it is.) You're obviously working in a different plumbing vernacular if those are your typical fitting types (we have similar, but they are not common for basic connections. Have seen other posts from your general direction where they are used for everything.) Supply **to** the water heater should be large.

Comment: If piping is short (apparently for everything but the hot to the kitchen) then pipe diameter does not need to be terribly small to minimize "pushing cold water" - also insulate the pipes very well, especially if using copper hot water pipes, which conduct heat from the water heater.

Comment: One question per post, please. See [ask] and take the [tour]. If you wish to recover the second and third questions for reposting, they're in the [edit history](https://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/257645/revisions).

Comment: Are those sizes inside diameter or outside diameter? here in the UK we rarely use anything less than 15mm outside diameter for anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whatever size they are bringing into the kitchen, I would bring into the water heater. Tee off before the water heater with the same size and then 12 mm to all fixtures. Use the same size out of the water heater and tee off to each fixture that needs hot water. Don't forget to go back to the kitchen with hot water. 12 mm will be fine for the tee offs. The metal sleeves you're showing are not needed with copper piping.

Comment: This sounds smart, but I'm a bit confused by the fact that here in Sweden there is a mix of metrical and imperial system... For example: the inlet of the shower is 1/2" while the tap of the sink is 3/8" (if I don't mistake these are "nominal" sizes, not the actual ones). Following your reasoning I should use a bigger pipe for the shower then for the sink. Which is the correct (copper) pipe diameter, in millimeters, for a 1/2 inch thread? 15mm?

Comment: Use the 1/2" pipe for all fixtures except the water heater. The 1/2" will fit into the shower. Use the 1/2" for the sink. Put a 1/2" x 3/8" shutoff valve on the end of the 1/2" pipe and a 3/8" to 3/8"  connector from shutoff valve to sink tap. 1/2" thread would be 15mm.  I believe 1/2" pipe would be 22mm.